# How to exclude Chapter 0 using fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am using the \documentclass{report}, and I want to change two things in my header and footer.

The first relates to "\fancyfoot[L]{Chapter \thechapter}"; I want to start from Chapter 1, but Chapter 0 appears in the footer in the front matter.

Secondly, I would like to include the chapter title in the header.

```
% Header/footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[L]{Chapter \thechapter}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
```

Comment: As always on this site, ease provide a full but minimal, self contained example that shows your problem. The example should be such that others can copy your code and try it with out altering it or adding to it.

Comment: Generally you are doing your headers wrong. Don't write `Chapter \thechapter` directly into the header like that. Have `\chapter` send that data to the header via its mark functionality. Thus use `\leftmark` and `\rightmark` as the two marks the headers write to. Additionally chapter only adds a number when there is none.